# Given a set of Hough line with many outliers, how can I detect quadrilateral shape in it?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

How can I quadrilateral when there is extreme amount of outlier

I have tried naive combinatorial search, the speed is painfully slow

Below shows a example that has 222 hough line detected
[image]

Update: Here are the original input and the canny edge output
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide your code, input image and so on?

Comment: Maybe this paper can give you some hints (It's exactly about your problem): http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6460077/?reload=true

Comment: The paper described a glorified combinatorial search which did not address the problem of huge amount of outliners

Comment: Which one of the quadrilaterals? There are dozens.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to discretize the lines and run a `PCA` algorithm on it. It will give you a quadliteral shape. `PCA` (principal component analysis) is exactly made for that kind of stuff (detecting main coordinates).

However, there should be a nicer way without discretization.

Comment: can you elaborate on the PCA solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to extract the tennis court? You have a lot more information in those images than just the lines. Color would seem the most promising.